# What is the opposite of pollutant, in the sense of "victim" or "casualty"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am busy writing a report where I need a word which would mean "the recipient of pollution".

Specifically I want to mention domestic sewerage which has been polluted by industrial sewerage.

The reason I don't want to describe it is because the word I am looking for should be the header in the column of a table.

thank you all for the help around here!

Comment: And therefore "recipient of pollution" is too long, right?

Comment: that is the problem yes ... I would like to hammer the issue home by saying "victim" but it just sounds odd

Comment: I've just seen the synonyms of "recipient" and there is no suitable word either. Hmm...

Comment: If there are no synonyms applicable, you might want to resort to figure of speech. :)

Comment: Maybe pollutee?

Answer (score 3):

How about *contaminated*? (here meaning subjected or exposed to contamination by the pollutant)

Comment: Although it's an adjective, I think a noun-like use would work in something like a column heading, equivalent to "contaminated thing"

Answer (score 2):

"Victim" is more appropriate. That would be my choice if I were you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Though it is not a single word,

**Affected Party** could work. You could substitute the word 'party' with something more appropriate to your context like households.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that a single word for this exists, and I can't think of a functional ending that can be applied well to derive one (*pollutee*, in my opinion, is ambiguous as the *-ee* ending often, but doesn't always, denote the recipient of the verb's action).

In this case, then, I'd simply recommend *polluted* (using the adjective as a noun) if you require a one-word answer.  As suggested above, *contaminated* also works in the same way and for most contexts would probably be interchangeable.